# Making my jquery slider responsive

Tags: html, css

I've created my jquery slider, and now I'm having issues trying to make it responsive. the navigation dots and navigation buttons can be positioned at fixed height. But I want to position next button to the center right of the carousel and wanted to do it in %. so, I give height:100% to its parent body, #container, #carousel. and it worked but the page scaled as you can see in the demo I provided. any suggestion how to position the #next,#prev in percentages?

Here is my work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpXmQj

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
Css html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
header {
  background: black;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 1.5em;
  color: white;
}
#carousel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.sliderbuttons {} #prev,
#next {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 148, 41, 0.68);
  box-shadow: 2px white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Baloo Tamma', cursive;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  /*making the prev,next on top of content*/
  z-index: 2;
}
#prev {
  left: 0;
}
#next {
  right: 0;
}
.active {
  z-index: 1;
}
.indicators {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 49%;
  left: 45%;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.indicators div {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.blip {
  background-color: orange;
}
div.indicators:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Image carousel</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carouselcss.css">
  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma" rel="stylesheet"> -->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      header is here
    </header>
    <div id="carousel">
      <div class="sliderbuttons">
        <input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="&gt;">
        <input type="button" name="next" id="prev" value="&lt;">
      </div>
      <div class="slides">
        <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1_ukaavUI.jpg" alt="image1" class="slide active">
        <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/green-Rice-1600x900.jpg" alt="image2" class="slide">
        <img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-10.jpg" alt="image3" class="slide">

      </div>
      <div class="indicators">
        <div class="circle blip"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just to clarify you're having positioning problems right?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: I want to position next button to the center right of the carousel and wanted to do it in %. so, I give height:100% to its parent body, #container, #carousel. and it worked but the page scaled as you can see in the demo I provided. any suggestion how to position the #next,#prev in percentages without any scale problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amVJWd) out. I believe what was happening was that your next and prev were adjusting to the height of the screen and not the height of the images like you were hoping.

So to customize this, first set the height and width of your images to whatever you want, match that same height for your buttons, and as long as they're in the same parent div it should match

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Image carousel</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carouselcss.css">
<!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma" rel="stylesheet"> -->

</head>
<body>
<header>
header is here
</header>
<div id="carousel">
<div class="sliderbuttons">
<input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="&gt;">
<input type="button" name="prev" id="prev" value="&lt;">
</div>
<div class="slides">
    <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1_ukaavUI.jpg" alt="image1" class="slide active">
    <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/green-Rice-1600x900.jpg" alt="image2" class="slide">
    <img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-10.jpg" alt="image3" class="slide">

</div>
<div class="indicators">
    <div class="circle blip"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>


</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>

html,body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



#container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

header {
    background: black;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 1.5em;
    color: white;
}

#carousel {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink

} 

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.sliderbuttons {
}

#prev,#next {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 148, 41, 0.68);
    box-shadow: 2px white;
    border:none;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 1%;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Baloo Tamma', cursive;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    /*making the prev,next on top of content*/
    z-index: 2;
}
#prev {
    left:0;
}
#next {
    right:0;
}

.active {
    z-index: 1;
}

.indicators {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:49%;
    left: 45%;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 5px;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.indicators div {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;

}

.blip {
    background-color: orange;
}

div.indicators:hover {
    cursor: pointer;

}
```